# How to hide gridlines of cells using WriteHTML

Tags: php, tcpdf

i'm making some changes in a  PDF using TCPDF, but once i generate it the cells are getting gridlines,
how can i remove them ?

My PHP Code:

```
 // set Constants...

    $html = "<style type='text/css'>span { font-size: 8pt; } </style><span>$dateNew</span>";

    for($top = 0; $top < 6 ; $top++)
    {   
        $ausgabey = $starty + $tempy;
        for($left = 0; $left < 3 ; $left++)
        {
                $ausgabex = $startx +  $tempx   ;   

                $pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
                $pdf->StartTransform();
                $pdf->SetTopMargin($ausgabey);
                $pdf->SetLeftMargin($ausgabex);
                $pdf->Rotate($rotate);          
                $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
                $pdf->StopTransform();

                $tempx = $tempx + $stepx;
        }
        $tempx = 0;
        $tempy = $tempy + $stepy;
    }

    $pdf->Output("$dateiname.pdf",'I');
```

the Original PDF doesn't have gridlines, but after running my code the PDF cells are getting gridlines, why?